# AVPlayerViewController in UIViewControllerRepresentable to fit container ZStack?

Tags: swiftui

I am adding a view in a ZStack. The view comes from a `UIViewControllerRepresentable`:

```
struct MyPlayerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    var url: URL
            
    func updateUIViewController(_ playerController: AVPlayerViewController, context: Context) {
        
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> AVPlayerViewController {
        let vc = AVPlayerViewController()
        let player = MyPlayer(url: url)
        vc.player = player
        vc.player?.play()
        return vc
    }
            
}
```

The View I add `MyPlayerView` is very simple:

```
var myContainer: some View {
    
    ZStack {


        MyPlayerView(url: vUrl)


    }

}
```

In the view `myContainer` is used, I do set its frame:

```
myContainer
.frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.width)
```

When `MyPlayerView` loads, it bleeds out left and right, but, it fits to the exact height of the ZStack.

Like this:

[image]

How can I make `MyPlayerView` show the video inside the ZStack so the video can be fully visible?

Comment: In SwiftUI containers (`ZStack` in this case) tights to content view/s, not vise versa.